# Vaadin - pass data to different UI

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I am new to Vaadin and I tried to find the answer to this by searching SO as well as Google so any help will be appreciated or at least point me in the right direction.

My app navigates from one view to another using the following logic

```
ActivitiesUI startUpActivity = new ActivitiesUI();
UI.getCurrent().setContent(startUpActivity.buildMainArea());
```

I need to know how I can pass data (like a String or an int) from the current UI to the one being navigated to (in this case startUpActivity)

Coming from an Android background, I am thinking along the lines of an Intent

Comment: In vaadin you have classes where you can either pass the parameters to the new activity via arguments, or you have some properties in the main UI class. It realy depends on what lifetime the data has

Comment: You can take a look at the [Vaadin book navigator chapter](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.navigator.html) and the [wiki navigation with vaadin-spring page](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=3&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com+wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=III+-+Views+and+Navigation+with+Vaadin+Spring) if you're using Spring as well.

Comment: Can't you just pass values to the buildMainArea method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging into the Wiki, I ended up using the [Http Session](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/main/setting+and+reading+session+attributes) to set and get the variables and it is working fine.